# Netbeans Java: Where to put my CSV file?

Tags: java, csv, netbeans

I followed a tutorial to create some simple code to output the contents of a csv file. However, I always get the following message:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Data.csv (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:656)
at testing.csv.files.Test.main(Test.java:26)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

So I guess this means that the program is running, but it can't find my csv file. Basically, I just dragged and dropped it from my desktop into the "Source Packages" file in my Java Project, which is where my Test.java file is. I've also tried putting it in the "testing.csv.files", but that did not work either. Neither did putting it in the "Test Packages".

I've ran out of ideas. Where am I supposed to put this csv file?

here is my code:

```
package testing.csv.files;


 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //.csv comma separated values
    String fileName = "Data.csv";
    File file = new File(fileName); // TODO: read about File Names
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputStream.hasNext()){
            String data = inputStream.next();
            System.out.println(data);
        }
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It should work if u put the file in your project root folder.

Comment: Yes, it is looking for "Data.csv".  Java goes by no base OS unless specified

Comment: `new File("").getAbsolutePath()`

Comment: as code you have given you have specified `String fileName = "Data.csv";` for that i have answered it correctly and if you run your program on different system it will fail if you use 
`Desktop/Data.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try pointing to the full path of the file.

For example:  `String fileName = "Desktop/Data.csv";`

FYI - You can copy the full path of a file by right clicking on a file while holding shift, then selecting: "copy as path".

Comment: I like your idea. However, when I tried it, it says that I am using an illegal character, which I think it is referring to the "\".         Here is what the file location for me is:                                "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Data.csv"

Comment: Sorry it should be forward slash "/". Make sure you get the actual path  of your file though, I was just putting it as an example in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, now it works! Its weird that I have to manually change it from back slash to forward slash.

Comment: Path location is different in windows and ... everyone else. If you want to use  "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Data.csv" as your location, then escape the back slash with  "C:\\Users\\Owner\\Desktop\\Data.csv"

Answer (score 0):

Put your `csv` file(i.e `Data.csv`) in your project folder then it will work properly i tried your code it works fine for me

Comment: I don't know where exactly you mean. I have tried dragging and dropping it into all of the possible areas within my project that are visible on the top right area of my screen navigator for files, and they all resulted in errors.

Comment: i think you are using netbeans or eclipse. when you create a project a folder is created with the name you specified paste that csv file there.

Comment: for example when you create java application through netbeans/eclipse you give name to that project.and save that some where in your system get thet path and paste that csv file there

Comment: Just putting a file in the project won't solve the issue if the file is not loaded as a resource or if the file is not referenced by the full location.